# Ajax upload not working on IE9/Chrome

Tags: javascript, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

I have a standard file upload script using [this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) script. When the upload is completed, I send back a JSON telling the client that the upload went OK, something like this:

```
{done: true, error: "No error"}
```

When I do the upload on Firefox, everything works out smoothly, but on IE9 / Chrome it breaks. IE tells me that I need to download the file, something like this image:

[image: IE9's download dialog]

I thought that the issue was the headers submitted to the client and I tried setting the content type to:

- application/javascript
- text/javascript

The files are stored properly and the answer is coming back without any corruption, nor in the encoding, or gzipped or anything like it.

**Any ideas?**

**EDIT:** Forgot to add the link on the ***"this"*** and also, it's an older version of the plugin, not the current one.

Comment: If IE is trying to download it, it's gotta be a headers issue. Post more of your code – how you make the upload request and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll reply the question myself because I've found a solution, at least it works...

Thing is that when sending a request using an iframe, seems that the content type of the response shouldn't be either `application/json` or `application/javascript` or any other like it. My solution was to send the response as `text/html`, and do a `JSON.parse` on the client, and it works like a charm.

Since I all of my Ajax calls specify that I expect a JSON, it works ok when I make ajax calls as well, because jQuery handles the whole conversion, only thing that worries me is any problem related to performance on the client, but I see no signs of problem just yet...

Hope that anybody that runs with the problem may find my answer helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the same upload widget and IE 8 in the past.

`header('Content-Type: application/json')` fixed it for me. Did you try this as well?

Comment: @DavidConde: Then post the request and (most importantly) the response headers. Should give more insight into what's going on.